# People please tell me what does "tho" mean!

Tags: word-meaning

I saw a comment on social media that "She is cute tho".
What did he mean when said that?

Comment: ***Yo, bro!*** It's just short for ***though*** *(**however**).* Easy to establish using a Google search for [*define tho*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+tho&oq=define+tho&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4327j1j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I would say it is an informal alternative spelling for _though_. It is shorter only in writing - no different when you speak.

Answer (score 1):

**Tho** is an [alternate spelling](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tho) of "though," often used when people want to type is few letters as possible.  It is naturally popular on twitter, where you have count your characters, but it's actually been around in English for well over 100 years. It is considered non-standard and should not be used in writing where you want to be taken seriously.

Occasionally, you do see it used humorously by people who are sarcastically imitating brainless internet speak (see also: [teh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teh)).  There's even an internet meme called [Y THO](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/y-tho) (pronounced "why, though?") that's used to ask why someone did something really stupid or strange.  Knowing whether someone is humorous or merely concise with "tho" would depend on context.